# How to combine two spatial functions in one union query

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgis, psql

I want to find out the intersection and difference in the same query using PostgreSQL (the logic should be same for other databases).

How can I combine both ST_Intersection and ST_Difference in the same query and return the result.

I tried:

```
select 1 as keys,(st_intersection(tale1.the_geom,table2.the_geom)) from table1,table2 
UNION select ,st_difference(table1.the_geom,table2.the_geom) from table1,table2;
```

But it returned an error saying error after select ^ ,st_difference(....

Comment: Some effort seems to have been make with this question, so I have made an effort to answer it, even thought it seems to be part of the current series of assignment problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues: you have 2 columns in first select and only one in the 2nd, plus you have a comma in from of ST_Difference, where presumably you wanted to put a 2 or somesome. You can simplify the query somewhat by selecting the geoms from table1 and table2 in a With query, and then unioning them, eg,

```
 with geoms (geom1, geom2) as 
   (select a.the_geom, b.the_geom from table1 a, table2 b) 
 select 1, st_intersection(geom1, geom2) from geoms where st_intersects(geom1, geom2)
   union 
 select 2, st_difference(geom1, geom2) from geoms where st_intersects(geom1, geom2);
```

Note the additions of where ST_Intersects(geom1, geom2) in both queries -- this will restrict the intersection and difference to those polygons that at least have some intersection, avoiding a cartesian join. Ideally you should have where a.id != b.id in there too, to avoid self-intersection/difference, but you get the idea, I hope.